# 'Char' error returned when running varexo in dynare/matlab

Tags: matlab, variables, var, assign

every time I try and assign an exogenous variable in matlab with the command

```
varexo g;
```

it returns the error that it cannot take the 'char' input

i have used this function before, and this is how it says it is used in the documentation.

What is going on?

Comment: Did you try posting on the Dynare forums? The user community there is pretty active.

Comment: `Undefined function or variable 'varexo'.` Your code is not reproducible in Matlab.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that this is not Matlab code, but rather Dynare syntax. You cannot invoke Dynare syntax in Matlab. Rather you must call dynare from within Matlab on your mod-file for the preprocessor to translate your mod-file to Matlab code. See e.g. [here for more details](http://www.dynare.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=4426)